# C# Login to Load on Main Form

Tags: c#

I have 2 Forms, Login(Form2) and Main(Form1) form. I want to load the Main form after typing the username and password correct and hide/close the login form at the same time.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = "admin";
        string password = "admin";
        if ((textBox1.Text == username) && (textBox2.Text == password))
            MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");

        else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login");


    }
```

Comment: See my two form project : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

If login success first hide the  `Login(Form2)` form then show the `Main(Form1)` form

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = "admin";
        string password = "admin";
        if ((textBox1.Text == username) && (textBox2.Text == password))
        {
           this.Visible=false;
           Form1 form1 = new Form1();
           form1.show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    this.Visible=false;
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    form1 .ShowDialog(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = usernameTextBox.Text ;
        string password = passwordTextBox.Text ;
        if (checkDatabaseForValidDetails(username,password))
        {
           this.Visible=false;
           Form1 formObject = new Form1();
           formObject.show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
        }

    }
```